# What's the easiest way to duplicate NSMenuItems ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What's the easiest way to duplicate NSMenuItems ?

I need to programmatically add the same menu items to 2 different menus. I can't reuse the same one.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMenuItem conforms to NSCopying, so simply copy it:

```
NSMenuItem* duplicateItem = [originalItem copy];
```

Comment: Ya.. thanks. If I want to sync the 2 menus, should I use bindings ? (For syncing I mean update the submenus on both menus...)

Comment: If you mean to bind two corresponding items to the same object, then yes it's a good idea.